# h2o session initializing and closing immediately on h2o.init in Pycharm IDE

Tags: python, pycharm, h2o, h2o4gpu

I have installed official h2o package in Pycharm IDE as below image and after installing when I am initializing h2o using h2o.init(), h2o session starting and closing immediately.Please suggest why it is closing immediately.

[image]

```
import h2o
h2o.init(ip="localhost", port=54323)


:\Users\sarvendra.singh\PycharmProjects\H2o\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/sarvendra.singh/PycharmProjects/H2o/main.py
Checking whether there is an H2O instance running at http://localhost:54323 ..... not found.
Attempting to start a local H2O server...
; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)
  Starting server from C:\Users\sarvendra.singh\PycharmProjects\H2o\venv\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\bin\h2o.jar
  Ice root: c:\users\sarven~1.sin\appdata\local\temp\tmpmhrvqf
  JVM stdout: c:\users\sarven~1.sin\appdata\local\temp\tmpmhrvqf\h2o_sarvendra_singh_started_from_python.out
  JVM stderr: c:\users\sarven~1.sin\appdata\local\temp\tmpmhrvqf\h2o_sarvendra_singh_started_from_python.err
  Server is running at http://127.0.0.1:54323
Connecting to H2O server at http://127.0.0.1:54323 ... successful.
Warning: Your H2O cluster version is too old (8 months and 19 days)! Please download and install the latest version from http://h2o.ai/download/
--------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------
H2O_cluster_uptime:         03 secs
H2O_cluster_timezone:       Asia/Kolkata
H2O_data_parsing_timezone:  UTC
H2O_cluster_version:        3.30.0.1
H2O_cluster_version_age:    8 months and 19 days !!!
H2O_cluster_name:           H2O_from_python_sarvendra_singh_y4j13p
H2O_cluster_total_nodes:    1
H2O_cluster_free_memory:    3.535 Gb
H2O_cluster_total_cores:    4
H2O_cluster_allowed_cores:  4
H2O_cluster_status:         accepting new members, healthy
H2O_connection_url:         http://127.0.0.1:54323
H2O_connection_proxy:       {"http": null, "https": null}
H2O_internal_security:      False
H2O_API_Extensions:         Amazon S3, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, TargetEncoder, Core V4
Python_version:             2.7.18 final
--------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------
Closing connection _sid_973f at exit
H2O session _sid_973f closed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using PyCharm to run your code.  If you prefer an interactive session, I would recommend that you utilize the "Python Console" to input your commands.  This will maintain the session open so that you can access the Flow GUI from your browser, while maintaining your ability to inject your Python dataframes into the java server.

As an aside, I found difficulty importing csv files using Flow, but Python dataframes could be used to pipe the data into the process without error.